# How does one achieve the Big Mello effect?

Tags: plug-ins, effect

Big Mello used to apply an interesting effect to his vocals, for example in [Charge It 2 Da Game](https://youtu.be/VHw7iJG0UfU?t=24s) and [No Hidin Place](https://youtu.be/lPbDDqVgvN4?t=9s).

It sounds to me as if a very short sample is looped for a bit, to create the glitchy "dragging" effect.

Can anyone recommend a method to achieve this effect, perhaps through a VST plugin? I would like to apply the effect left and right throughout a track.